# Change the data format

Tags: oracle, date, format

I use a script in oracle which select at a moment a date :

```
CURSOR SAURON IS select TOUTDOUX_ID, TYPE_OF_ACTION, USER_ID, PROFILE_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, PLATFORM, COMMENTS, PERM_FLAG, ACTIVE_FLAG from uam.tout_doux
```

But the format (25-JUL-2013) is not the one I expected (2013/07/25).
How can I select the date with the right format ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Oracle [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm) function with [date-time format elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#BABEFHFG). In your case you want the format string `YYYY/MM/DD`:

```
CURSOR SAURON IS
  select TOUTDOUX_ID, TYPE_OF_ACTION, USER_ID, PROFILE_NAME,
  TO_CHAR(START_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS SDate,
  TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS EDate,
  PLATFORM, COMMENTS, PERM_FLAG, ACTIVE_FLAG
from uam.tout_doux
```